# Why does the compiler complain about the assignment?

Tags: c, variable-assignment

While compiling the following code, the compiler produces the warning:

*assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type*

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 char * cp;
 const char *ccp;
 cp = ccp;
}
```

And this code is ok(no warning).Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 char * cp;
 const char *ccp;
 ccp = cp;
}
```

**Edit: Then why isn't this ok?**

```
int foo(const char **p) 
{ 
  // blah blah blah ...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 foo(argv);
}
```

Comment: In order to prevent (or at least warn) you from attempting to change constant data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because adding constness is a "safe" operation (you are restricting what you can do to the pointed object, which is no big deal), while removing constness is not (you promised not to touch the pointed object through that pointer, and now you are trying to take back your promise).

---

As for the additional question, it's explained in the C-Faq: http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html. Simply told, allowing that conversion would allow another kind of "unsafe" behavior:

```
int give_me_a_string(const char **p) 
{ 
    const char *str="asd";
    *p=str; // p is a pointer to a const pointer, thus writing
            // a in *p is allowed
}

int main()
{
    char *p;
    give_me_a_string(&ptrs); //< not actually allowed in C
    p[5]='a'; // wooops - I'm allowed to edit str, which I promised
              // not to touch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you're taking a pointer to data that must not be modified (`const`), and assigning it to a pointer that allows modification of it's data. Bad and dangerous.

In the second case, you're taking a non-const pointer and assigning it to a pointer that can cause *less* trouble than the original. You're not opening yourself up to any harmful, illegal or undefined actions.